# error squaring variables from imported data in r

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to create squared versions of variables "a" and "b" for the first part of a regression problem, but I am getting a weird error. I know how to run the regression, I just need to create the new terms first. I've used this command in the past, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. I'm operating in R studio on a Mac.

Code plus error posted below.

Thanks!

```
setwd("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop")

data <- read.csv("aas2_project2.csv")

a2 <- a^2
Error: object 'a' not found
> View(data)
> b2 <- b^2
Error: object 'b' not found
```

Comment: Don't do that. Tell your regression function to square the variables for you, e.g., `lm(y ~ a + I(a^2), data = data)` or preferably use `poly` in the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are in your `data` object. Try: `data$a2 <- data$a^2`, etc. When you eventually get to the regression, you specify your data.frame (`data`) as an argument to `lm`:

```
lm(y ~ a + a2, data = data)
```

This can be confusing if your data are stored in an object called `data` because `data` is the name of an argument used by many functions. So you may want to use a different name, like `dat <- read.csv("aas2_project2.csv")`.